# Is it possible to see old notifications?

Tags: notification, dropbox, inotify

I recently changed some settings in my inotify configuration so that phpstorm would be able to index my files better(I think?).  Now my dropbox installation is on the fritz.  It can't scan through my filesystem.

I got a notification from the Dropbox app on my screen telling me to run a command to fix the issue, however the notification disappeared before I had a chance to enter the command.  Is it possible to see a log of these notifications or something like that?

Edit: The notification popped up again so I took a screenshot of the command, but would still like to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install something beforehand:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jconti/recent-notifications
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-notifications
```

Comment: The most recent release (here in 2023) of `recent-notifications` is for Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty